# laravel 4 route not found - defaults to show method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I've had this working but now a route is no longer found and I can't see why.

In a javascript function I am making an ajax post to the function with this url:

```
url: '/customers/storeajax',
```

In my routes.php file I have the following routes:

```
Route::post('customers/storeajax', array('as'=>'storeajax', 'uses' => 'CustomersController@storeAjax'));

Route::post('customers/updateajax/{id}', array('as'=>'updateajax','uses' => 'CustomersController@updateAjax'));


Route::resource('customers', 'CustomersController');
```

Now when I try to POST to the storeajax route I get a `ModelNotFoundException` which to me means the route could not be found so it defaults to the default customers controller show method - in the error log I can see the following entry:

```
#1 [internal function]: CustomersController->show('storeajax')
```

confirming its treating the storeajax as a parameter.

I've placed my additional routes above the default resource route

I've had this working before I can't see where I've gone wrong.

In addition these routes are placed in a group:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'sentryAuth'), function () {}
```

which simply ensures user is logged on. To test though I've removed outside the group and at the top of the file but still they don't work.

The url in my browser is coming up correctly as: `http://greenfees.loc/customers/storeajax` (which I can see in firebug console

I'm using POST as the ajax method - just to confirm

Can anyone see why this route doesn't work and what I've missed?

Update:

Here's the method inside the controller:

```
public function storeAjax()    
{        
$input = Input::all();    
$validation = Validator::make($input, Customer::$rules);    
if ($validation->passes())    
    {            
    $customer = $this->customer->create($input);            
    return $customer;        
    }    
return Redirect::route('customers.create')->withInput()
    ->withErrors(validation)            
    ->with('message', 'There were validation errors.');    
}
```

I'm 99% certain though that my route is not reaching this method (i've tested with a vardump inside the method) and the issue relates to my route `customer/storeajax` cannot be found.

What I think is happening is as `customer/storeajax` is not found in the list of routes starting with `customer` it is then defaulting to the resource route that appears on the list and thinks this is a restful request and translating it as `customer` route which defualts to the `show` method and using the `storeajax` as the parameter which then throws the error `modelnotfoundexception` because it cant find a customer with an id of 'storeajax'

This is evidence by the log detailing a call to the show method as above.

So for some reason my route for '/customers/storeajax' cannot be found even though it appears to be valid and appears before the customers resource. The modelnotfoundexception is a red herring as the cause is because of the routes defaulting to the resource constroller of customers when it cant find a route.

Comment: Try (in your JS): `url: '{{URL::route("storeajax")}}',` (assumed you're using blade)

Comment: Hi. The script is in a seperate script not in a blade template so cant use that method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by renaming the method in the controller to 'newAjax' and also updating the route to:

```
Route::post('customers/new', array('as'=>'newajax','uses' => 'CustomersController@newAjax'));
```

the terms `store` I assume is used by the system (restful?) and creating unexpected behaviour. I tested it in a number of other functions in my controller - adding the term `store` as a prefix to the method then updating the route and each time it failed.

Something learned.

Comment: This seems to be an environment dependant issue. On Windows+PHP 5.4.16 I have no issues. On CentOS+PHP5.4.23 I experience the same issue: "PUT" on `Route::resource('tasks', 'TasksController');` runs `TasksController.show()` instead of `TasksController.update()`. Weird!

Answer (score 2):

A route not being found raises a **NotFoundHttpException**.

If you are getting a **ModelNotFoundException** is because your route is firing and your logic is trying to find a **Model**, wich it can't somehow, and it is raising a not found error.

Are you using `FindOrFail()`? This is an example of method that raises this exception. `BelongsToMany()` is another one that might raise it.

Comment: If a resource controller exists if a route such as mine cannot be found it tries to find the restful method in the resource controller-I established that the resource route needs to appear after any related routes that are not restful to avoid it taking over. It's treating my url as a restful route to the show method and then coming up with the model not found error. If I remove my resource controller as a test I get the route not fiund error just to confirm assumption.

Comment: If you remove the route and then get a route not found error, it's because the route was working fine before.  My suspicion is `CustomersController::storeAjax()` is attempting to find a model that is trying to relate to a different model through one of the Eloquent relating methods that doesn't exist.  Show us your `Customer` model and any models `Customer` is trying to relate to.